# ASP.NET MVC nested query parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Ok, this is a bit tricky. I'm implementing a forum in ASP.NET MVC 3. The user wants to post a question, if not logged he gets redirected to the logon page. A returnUrl parameter is passed to the logon page. However, the returnUrl parameter also contains another returnUrl parameter. So the returnUrl parameter passed to the logon page looks like this:

```
"/forum/NewTopic?boardId=8&returnUrl=%2Fforum%2FBoard%2F8"
```

But, Request["returnUrl"] looks like this:

```
"/forum/NewTopic?boardId=8&returnUrl=%2Fforum%2FBoard%2F8,/forum/Board/8"
```

Notice the appended bit at the end, that shouldn't be there should it? How do I get the proper returnUrl?

However, when having a string returnUrl argument in the controller's action method, this will have the correct returnUrl value.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in MVC3 also, check if the redirecting page is "Login", set a flag, not to add the `returnUrl` parameter (which is the last appended bit at the end).

This way it does not get populated again.

Comment: In this case I ended up using a string returnUrl argument in the controller action, because it works correctly even with the nested parameter. I am just curious how to get the same result from the Request. Obviously asp.net mvc knows how to do it, otherwise the action argument wouldn't be correctly set, but until now I haven't found out how. Also I don't understand why the results are different with the 2 different way of getting query parameters.